# Problem when converting bash to python using bash2py

Tags: shell-script, python

Don't know if this is the right forum for this, but I have a problem with converting bash script to python with bash2py. I've run the installer, and it all seems fine.

```
Beginning configuration for bash-4.3-release for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for strerror in -lcposix... no
...
ls -l bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 johannes johannes 5190160 jan  6 12:28 bash 
size bash
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1093876   46840   24080 1164796  11c5fc bash
mv bash bash2pyengine
cp bash2pyengine ~/bin/bash2pyengine
-rwxr-xr-x 1 johannes johannes 5190160 jan  6 12:28 bash2pyengine
```

When I try to run it though, it can't find the command (It's in danish but hopefully yo get the idea)

```
johannes@JohaDebian:~/Hentet/bash2py/bash2py-3.6$ bash2pyengine -f 
/home/johannes/Dokumenter/check_temp.sh 
bash: bash2pyengine: kommando ikke fundet  
johannes@JohaDebian:~/Hentet/bash2py/bash2py-3.6$
```

I've added the bin folder to `$PATH`

```
johannes@JohaDebian:~/Hentet/bash2py/bash2py-3.6$ export 
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

and I've made it executable (I think)

```
johannes@JohaDebian:~/Hentet/bash2py/bash2py-3.6/bin$ cd
johannes@JohaDebian:~$ cd bin
johannes@JohaDebian:~/bin$ ls
bash2pyengine
johannes@JohaDebian:~/bin$ chmod +x ~/bin/bash2pyengine
```

Comment: The exact wording of the error message is usually important. So please run `LC_ALL=C bash2pyengine -f /home/johannes/Dokumenter/check_temp.sh` so we can see the error in English. That said, please confirm that i) `~/bin` is in your `$PATH` and ii) that `~/bin/bash2pyengine` is executable.

Comment: @terdon Something happened when i did the steps you provided. Now I'm getting a segmentation error.
`johannes@JohaDebian:~/bin$ bash2pyengine -f /home/johannes/Dokumenter/check_temp.sh 
Segmentfejl`
I also get segmentation error when I try to run the command you specified, Was editing my comment, so didn't see yours :-) Editing question now.

Comment: That... doesn't really make sense. Please [edit] your question and show what you tried. Did you check the things I mentioned however? The problem is almost certainly either that `~/bin` is not in your PATH (it isn't by default, as far as I know, only Ubuntu adds this directory automatically) or that `~/bin/bash2pyengine` isn't executable.

Comment: "kommando ikke fundet" almost certainly means "command not found". It looks like you then managed to run `bash2pyengine` and that that crashed with a segmentation fault (a different problem).

Comment: @dhag So, as far as I can read about segmentation fault, the RAM is a problem?

Comment: @Techguy: The more likely cause for segmentation faults after running a newly-compiled program is a bug in said program.

Comment: @dhag so it's just too bad? Nothing to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I had also segmentation fault problem after trying to run bash2py when installation has already exited with 1 Error. But later, tried with the same version as in the video [uwaterloo bash2py homepage](https://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/index.html). Even when installing bash2py-2.3 had compilation warnings, it worked great, atleast to my expectation from an older version. With just one file out of several exited with:

```
Burp can't print
bash2pyengine: burp.c:54: increase_burp: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Thanks iterating files with a for loop, only one of the files suffered. Thanks the author for making and uploading a video.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation faults are related to the use of xmalloc in more recent versions of bash2py. Thanks to Pradeep's tip, I was able to isolate this by comparing the source for version 3.6 and 2.3. See the following Github issue for details:
https://github.com/clarity20/bash2py/issues/5.